# Perl Find - No such file or directory

Tags: perl, file, file-find

I am using File::Find and file i/o on a text file to parse a series of directories and move the contents into a new folder.  It is a simple script (see below):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;

my $dir = "/opt/CollectMinderDocuments/coastalalglive"; #base directory for Coastal documents

#read file that contains a list of closed IDs
open(MYDATA, "Closed.txt");

mkdir("Closed");

while(my $line = <MYDATA>) {
  chomp $line;
  my $str = "$dir" . "/Account$line";
  print "$str\n";
  find(\&move_documents, $str);
}
sub move_documents {
  my $smallStr = substr $File::Find::name, 43;
  if(-d) {
    #system("mkdir ~/Desktop/Closed/$smallStr");
    print "I'm here\n";
    system("mkdir /opt/CollectMinderDocuments/coastalalglive/Closed/$smallStr");
    #print "Made a directory: /opt/CollectMinderDocuments/coastalalglive/Closed/$smallStr\n";
  }
  else {
    print "Now I'm here\n";
    my $smallerStr = substr $File::Find::dir, 43;
    my $temp = "mv * /opt/CollectMinderDocuments/coastalalglive/Closed/$smallerStr/";
    system("$temp");
  }
}
```

The text file contains a list of numbers:

```
1234
2805
5467
```

The code worked when I executed it last month, but it is now returning a "file or directory not found" error. The actual error is **"No such file or directoryerDocuments/coastalalglive/Account2805"**.  I know all of the directories it is searching for exist.  I have manually typed in one of the directories, and the script executes fine:

```
find(\&move_documents, "/opt/CollectMinderDocuments/coastalalglive/Account2805/");
```

I am not sure why the error is being returned. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: That's not the actual error, the actual error would include a line number.

Comment: What do the system() commands return? $rc=system(...);print $rc>>8

Comment: Why are you using system calls instead of functions like `mkdir()` or `File::Copy->move()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error:

```
"No such file or directoryerDocuments/coastalalglive/Account2805"
```

Seems to imply that there is an `\r` that was not removed by your `chomp`. That will happen when transferring files between different file systems, where the file contains `\r\n` as line endings. The real error string would be something like:

```
/opt/CollectMinderDocuments/coastalalglive/Account2805\r: No such file or directory
```

Try changing `chomp $line` to `$line =~ s/[\r\n]+$//;` instead, and see if that works.

Also:

```
my $temp = "mv * /opt/CollectMinderDocuments/coastalalglive/Closed/$smallerStr/";
system("$temp");
```

Is very wrong. The first non-directory file in that loop will move all the remaining files (including dirs? not sure if `mv` does that by default). Hence, subsequent iterations of the subroutine will find nothing to move, also causing a "Not found" type error. Though not one caught by perl, since you are using `system` instead of `File::Copy::move`. E.g.:

```
move $_, "/opt/CollectMinderDocuments/coastalalglive/Closed/$smallerStr/" or die $!;
```